# Error when i try to show a specific Document from Firestore in a ion-card?

Tags: html, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to bring a specific document with a specific ID, I know how to bring it. The problem is when I try to show the document in the Html it does not let me.

Function to call service and get the document!

```js
 item:restaurantModel={
    id_doc: '',
    logo:'',
    descripcion:'',
    nombre:'',
    portada:'',
    idadmin:'',
  }
  
  ResDocument:AngularFirestoreDocument<restaurantModel>;
  ResObservable: Observable<restaurantModel>;
  
  this.idres=this.router.snapshot.params['id'];
           console.log(this.idres);
           this.ResDocument = this.resser.getSpecificRestaurant(this.idres);
           this.ResObservable=this.ResDocument.snapshotChanges().pipe(             
            map(actions => {
              const data = actions.payload.data() as any;
              const uid = actions.payload.id;
              return { uid, ...data};
            })            
          );

//really print the data from a specific document
          this.ResObservable.subscribe(datas => console.log(datas.descripcion));
```

Service:

```js
getSpecificRestaurant(id){
  return this.fs.doc<restaurantModel>("/restaurantes/"+id);
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of ResObservable | async ">
    
       
      
    <img src="{{item.portada}}">

   
 <ion-card-content>
   

    <ion-card-title>
        <h1>{{item.nombre}}</h1>
    </ion-card-title> 
  <p>{{item.descripcion}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Thanks for Your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*ngFor` you are using is over the observable rather than the data you obtain within the subscription. After seeing the data I do not think you need to use `*ngFor` as you only get back one object.

```
public items;

this.ResObservable.subscribe(datas => this.items = datas);
```

Then you can access the object directly in your template.

```
<div *ngIf="items">
    <ion-card>      
        <img src="{{ items.portada }}">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                <h1>{{ items.nombre }}</h1>
            </ion-card-title> 
            <p>{{ items.descripcion }}</p>
         </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

Comment: rror: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck this is the error

Comment: are you using angular 6?, please show what you get from console.log(datas);

Comment: yes, but with this option does not run, the error is:Type 'restaurantModel' is not assignable to type 'restaurantModel[]'.ts(2322)
Type 'restaurantModel' is missing the following properties from type 'restaurantModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more.ts(2740)

Comment: this.ResObservable.subscribe(datas => {this.items = datas; console.log(this.items); });    what does this show you, Would be able to give you the correct answer if i can see the datas

Comment: the problem is that when i put the line this.items=datas, the error is: Type 'restaurantModel' is missing the following properties from type 'restaurantModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more. When i show console.log(datas) the result is:{descripcion: "Crepes, Waffles y Helados", idadmin: "KODcVoTqjzNYBWJER7fTkA1cnzp1", logo: "http://logosenvector.com/logo/img/crepes-waffles-366.jpg", nombre: "Crepes & Waffles", portada: "https://revistalabarra.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/crepes-and-waffles-1500x800.jpg"}